# Rails: Elegant way to handle navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have a navigation partial that looks like this (x10 buttons)...

```
<% if current_controller == "territories" %>
    <li><%= link_to "Territories", {:controller => 'territories'}, :class => 'active'  %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Territories", {:controller => 'territories'}  %></li>
<% end %>
<% if current_controller == "contacts"  %>
    <li><%= link_to "Contacts", {:controller => 'Contacts'}, :class => 'active'  %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Contacts", {:controller => 'Contacts'}  %></li>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more elegant/DRY solution for doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a similar vein to what Chuck said:

```
<% TARGETS.each do |target| %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to target.humanize, 
      { :controller => target }, 
      class => ('active' if current_controller == target)) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to see where the repetition is in there. It's all of the general form:

```
<% if current_controller == XXXXX %>
  <li><%= link_to XXXXX, {:controller => XXXXX}, CLASS %></li>
<% else %>
  [do the same stuff minus ":class => 'active'"]
<% end %>
```

So we want XXXXX and CLASS to be variables (since those are the only things that change) and the rest can be a simple template.

So, we could do something like this:

```
%w(Contacts Territories).each |place|
  <% class_hash = current_controller == place ? {:class => 'active'} : {}
  <li><%= link_to place, {:controller => place}, class_hash)</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [rails-widgets](http://github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets/tree/master) on github. It provides a ton of convenience helpers for rails UI stuff (tabnavs, tooltips, tableizers, show hide toggle, simple css progressbar) in addition to navigation.

Here are the [docs](http://wiki.github.com/paolodona/rails-widgets)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`link_to_unless_current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001567). Not exactly what you asked for, but it's close.

Also, you could put this kind of logic in a helper to abstract it out of the view.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different version w/ link_to_unless_current:

```
<ul>
<% links.each do |link| -%>
<li><%= link_to_unless_current link.humanize, { :controller => target } %></li>
<% end -%>
</ul>
```

A good resource for stuff like this are the rails docs.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [simple-navigation plugin](http://github.com/andi/simple-navigation). It's an 'easy to use' rails plugin for creating navigations for your rails apps.